# Create a dynamic Expression<Func<TIn, TOut>> from a string

Tags: c#, linq, expression

I'm building a library for a REST API to allow documents in a Mongo database to be queried dynamically.

Assume the following `Person` entity:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Address Address { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public string Street { get; set; }
}
```

Now, I want to create an `Expression<Func<TInput, TOutput>>` which references a dynamic field.

Assume a method that accepts 2 strings, 1 representing the field to query and one representing the value, this method could look like:

```
public Expression<Func<TInput, TOutput>> Create<TInput, TOutput>(string fieldName, string fieldValue)
{
}
```

When the above method is called with a single property such as `Name`, an expression could be built relatively easily:

```
var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Person), string.Empty);
var field = Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter, "Name");
var expression = Expression.Lambda<Func<Person, string>>(field, parameter);
```

But how can I build an expression that exposes an embedded field such as `Address.Street`?

Kind regards

Comment: Did you have a chance to look at OData?

Comment: You should share how you would want to use that api. That's more likely to get you a response

Comment: I think that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45745858/5359302) would be helpful for you. You can check how it retrieve property with more than 1 level nesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a look at [ExpressionBuilder](https://github.com/dbelmont/ExpressionBuilder) project. It might help you a lot with your concerns. In [FilterBuilder](https://github.com/dbelmont/ExpressionBuilder/blob/3b157c6624d92390c91bf79c8ad64d6c5d330988/ExpressionBuilder/Builders/FilterBuilder.cs#L153), you find:

```
string parentName = memberName.Substring(0, memberName.IndexOf("."));
Expression parentMember = helper.GetMemberExpression(param, parentName);
```

And `GetMemberExpression` in [Helper Class](https://github.com/dbelmont/ExpressionBuilder/blob/3b157c6624d92390c91bf79c8ad64d6c5d330988/ExpressionBuilder/Helpers/BuilderHelper.cs#L13) does:

so it basically wraps multiple PropertyExpressions in a recursion (because the Expression could basically be "Address.Street.Number" etc.):

```
public Expression GetMemberExpression(Expression param, string propertyName)
{
    if (propertyName.Contains("."))
    {
        int index = propertyName.IndexOf(".");
        var subParam = Expression.Property(param, propertyName.Substring(0, index));
        return GetMemberExpression(subParam, propertyName.Substring(index + 1));
    }

    return Expression.Property(param, propertyName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    public static Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> Predicate<TEntity>(object value, string name, ExpressionType operation = ExpressionType.Equal)
    {
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TEntity), "entity");

        // Getting the names of the properties
        var properties = name.Split(".");

        //Getting the propety
        var property = Expression.Property(parameter, properties[0]);
        property = properties.Skip(1).Aggregate(property, Expression.Property);

        //Create a Constant Expression for the property value setting its type to be of type of the desired property
        var propertyValue = Expression.Constant(value, property.Type);

        //Making the comparison
        var comparison = Expression.MakeBinary(operation, property, propertyValue);

        //Creating the expression lambdaExpression.
        var expression = Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(comparison, parameter);

        //Converting the lambdaExpression to required Expression Type
        return expression.Cast<TEntity, bool>();
    }

    public static Expression<Func<TModel, TResult>> Cast<TModel, TResult>(this LambdaExpression expression)
    {
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<TModel, TResult>>(Expression.Convert(expression.Body, typeof(TResult)), expression.Parameters);
    }


    public static Expression<Func<TEntity, object>> GetExpression<TEntity>(this string order)
    {
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TEntity), "entity");
        var properties = order.Split(".");
        var property = properties.Skip(1).Aggregate(Expression.Property(parameter, properties[0]), Expression.Property);
        var expression = Expression.Lambda(typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(typeof(TEntity), property.Type), property, parameter);
        return expression.Cast<TEntity, object>();
    }
```